# AJAX call not redirecting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've implemented a login page with an AJAX request, that redirects the user depending on the response from the php page `loginrequest.php`

```
$.ajax ({

  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax/loginrequest.php",
  data: {
    username: username,
    password:pass
  },

  dataType: "text",

  success: function(html){

    console.log(html); // Prints 'login' or 'fail'

    if(html == 'login'){
      console.log("Yes"); //Never Printed
      window.location.href = 'index.php';
    }
    else if(html == 'fail'){
      alert("Incorrect Username and/or Password");
    }
  }
});
```

This is the `loginrequest.php` code that echos `login` or `fail` back to the AJAX function

```
if($count == 1){
  $bool = password_verify($mypassword, $row[1]);

  if($bool == true){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $myusername;
    $_SESSION['division'] = $row[2];
    $return = 'login';
  }
  else{
    $return = 'fail';
  }
}
else{
  $return = 'fail';
}
echo $return;
```

The `console.log` inside my success function prints login or fail depending on the credentials, but for some reason the if statement never evaluates to true. My page never redirects and it never displays the alert no matter what. I just uploaded these files to the web server, and they were working fine on WAMP but for some reason it's not working anymore. I tried `json_encode()` in `loginrequest.php` but it still wouldn't work. There is nothing wrong with my database call since it returns login or fail depending on the credentials, it's just that if statement in the success function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: May be a paste error, but you have a stray back tick ` at the end of your Ajax request.

Comment: do you see the request actually going out? (F12, network tab), what else is there happening after the request?

Comment: @pmahomme yea it's from pasting the code on here

Comment: Are you sure that the response you get in `html` is plain text and not an object containing response, status code etc.

Comment: @Jakumi yes and when I press login and hit refresh after it takes me to the home page because the `$_SESSION['user']` variable has been set and I have it setup so that it redirects you to the home page if you're logged in and try and access the login page

Comment: @vbrmnd I'm echoing a string from the php page and the console.log is showing a string, can it still be sending an object?

Comment: Hard to say. Can you setup an example page for us to see?

Comment: try changing `else if` to just `else`

Comment: What do you see in the console if you change `console.log(html);` to `console.log('"' + html + '"');`?

Comment: @pmahomme @ user866762 I'll try both your suggestions and get back to you, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that you have a stray whitespace being echo'd by PHP

Try

```
success: function(html){

    console.log(html); // Prints 'login' or 'fail'

    console.log(html.length); // Is it 5 and 4 respectively?

    html = $.trim(html); // if a space is the issue then this should fix it

    if(html == 'login'){
        console.log("Yes"); //Never Printed
        window.location.href = 'index.php';
    }
    else if(html == 'fail'){
        alert("Incorrect Username and/or Password");
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I used `if(html.indexOf("login") >= 0)` and it worked so I'm guessing it was a whitespace issue! I will accept your answer. I will try your method as well for completeness.

Answer (score -1):

Use true/false values like 1/0....more reliable

```
      if(html.trim() == 'login'){ //check and remove whitespace
         console.log("Yes");
          window.location.href = 'index.php';
      }
      else if(html.trim() == 'fail'){
          alert("Incorrect Username and/or Password");
      }
```